# GPT-J Python Script not found

Tags: python

I want to run GPT-J on the windows command line using CPU and I don't know how to start and where to code it. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `device_sample.py` script in the mesh-transformer-jax repo
https://github.com/kingoflolz/mesh-transformer-jax

You'll need to do some setup, like downloading the `slimmed-weights`, installing python and installing the python requirements. And you'll also have to add this line to the top `jax.config.update("jax_platform_name", "cpu")` which forces `jax` (a library meant to run on a cloud TPU) to use your cpu.

You can also use GPT-J from the HuggingFace `transformers` library. But that would require writing your own python script to take your input and feed it to the model.

Either way it'll probably require 16gb of RAM plus whatever your system needs at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Now that GPT-J is integrated in Hugging Face Transformers, the best way to test it is to use the pre-trained model from the Hugging Face hub:

```py
from transformers import GPTJForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
import torch

model = GPTJForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B", torch_dtype=torch.float16)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-j-6B")

prompt = (
    "In a shocking finding, scientists discovered a herd of unicorns living in a remote, "
    "previously unexplored valley, in the Andes Mountains. Even more surprising to the "
    "researchers was the fact that the unicorns spoke perfect English."
)

input_ids = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

gen_tokens = model.generate(
    input_ids,
    do_sample=True,
    temperature=0.9,
    max_length=100,
)

gen_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(gen_tokens)[0]
```

Doing this on a CPU will be extremely slow though...